# How do I use editortemplates in MVC3 for complex types?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, editortemplates

I have two classes, Vat and Product.  Product has a property of IVat.  I am trying to use editor templates in MVC to display a dropdown list of all the Vat objects when creating/editing a Product.  For the dear life of me I cannot get this working.

I have the following code which displays the dropdown but it does not set the Vat for the Product when the form gets submitted.

Controller:

```
IList<IVatRate> vatRates = SqlDataRepository.VatRates.Data.GetAllResults();
ViewBag.VatRates = new SelectList(vatRates, "Id", "Description");
```

Add.cshtml

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.VatRate.Id, "VatSelector", (SelectList)ViewBag.VatRates)
```

VatSelector.cshtml

```
@model SelectList
@Html.DropDownList(
        String.Empty /* */,
            (SelectList)ViewBag.Suppliers, 
        Model
    )
```

I would be grateful if anyone can shed some light on this or even point me to a good example on the web somewhere...I have been stuck with this for quite a few days now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use strongly typed views and view models as it makes things so much easier rather than ViewBag.

So start with a view model:

```
public class VatRateViewModel
{
    public string SelectedVatRateId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IVatRate> Rates { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new VatRateViewModel
        {
            Rates = SqlDataRepository.VatRates.Data.GetAllResults()
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(VatRateViewModel model)
    {
        // model.SelectedVatRateId will contain the selected vat rate id
        ...
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model VatRateViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.SelectedVatRateId,
        new SelectList(Model.Rates, "Id", "Description")
    )
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

And if you wanted to use editor template for the VatRateViewModel you could define one in `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/VatRateViewModel.cshtml`:

```
@model VatRateViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedVatRateId,
    new SelectList(Model.Rates, "Id", "Description")
)
```

and then whenever somewhere you have a property of type `VatRateViewModel` you could simply:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomePropertyOfTypeVatRateViewModel)
```

which would render the corresponding editor template.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Does the editortemplate have a separate controller?  If it does not then how would my Product's values get set, and if it does, where does it go and what should it be called?  I tried this before and could not get it to work.

Comment: Ok, LOTS of blood, sweat and tears later I FINALLY got it sorted.  I had to add all my complex types to the ViewModel, as well as my product.  Thanks again!