# Struct that behaves like DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, struct, attributes

I'm building a C#, MVC4 .NET web-application using client/serverside validation by adding custom attributes to my models properties.

In this project there are several forms where the user can enter an E-Mail address. Therefore each ViewModel has a `string` property EMailAddress decorated with attributes like `[CustomRequired][CustomEMail][CustomMinLength(13)][CustomMaxLength(200)]` to be sure that an Mail is valid and can be written to the database which only can store e.g. 200 characters.

No matter in which form the user could enter an EMail, it will always be stored in the same database-field. Therefore it would make sense to create a cutsom DataType `EMailAddress`.

I ended up with the following:

```
public struct EMailAddress
{
    [CustomMinLength(13)]
    [CustomMaxLength(200)]
    [CustomEMail]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    private EMailAddress(string value)
    {
        Address = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator EMailAddress(string value)
    {
         return new EMailAddress(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator EMailAddress(EMailAddress value)
    {
         return new value.Address ;
    }
}
```

In the ViewModel I would create a property of this type `EMailAddress` decorated with `[CustomRequired]` as of an EMail is not required on each part of the application.

What I want is a struct/class that behaves like the .NET `DateTime` struct. I can have a property of `DateTime` and in the View I simply can do:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateTimeProperty)
```

which will bind the value of the textbox to the underlying DateTime object. But this is not working for my custom struct as I would need to write something like

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EMailProperty.Address)
```

And I really don't like the `public string Address { get; set; }` in the struct.

Is .NET doing some "magic" when it encounters a DateTime object or how is this achieved? Am I completely on the wrong path or do I only miss a special part here? Maybe a class instead of a struct?

Comment: Is there something wrong with `string` for an email, and a `DateTime` for a DateTime?

Comment: You cannot extend standard TextBoxFor - it is compiled and works for predefined types. But, you can prepare own `DisplayTemplate` and `EditorTemplate`. Then you could use it as: `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.EMailProperty)`. Read more: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6324453/2160375

Comment: why won't you just use a class ?

Comment: I want to achieve a single class or struct which has the default validation rules applied, so I don't need to add the same attributes again and again each time I have an EMail-address. E.g. If I change the maxlength of the database to 250 I would only need to change one part in the code and all EMails are validated correctly against the new setup.

Comment: @chouaib: There is no reason not to use a class. Because of the DateTime behavior I thought strcut would be the type to chose. But I don't like the .Value approach because this I have to change in each view (which is for sure acceptable)